# Django admin: live update of change list page

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-admin

I use the Django admin "change list" page to monitor the state of objects created and updated by my site's users. I find myself frequently refreshing the page as my users do their work. Is there a good way to make it automatically refresh, so that I can see new changes within a few seconds? Looking for a technique that is easily reusable across my project's many "change list" pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an easy implantation you could set up a button to only refresh the changelist through an ajax call instead of the whole page (though setting it up with a view would be easier than changing the built in admin site without breaking anything). You can also set that function to refresh on a given interval.

Another option is to look at implementing Comet technology such as a push server. It would load new entries whenever they are added (like how Facebook does). It's rather complicated, but if you're up to it it might serve your purpose